# Declaring the same checked exception multiple times

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I have just realized that I can write a method declaring the same checked exception several times.

```
public void myMethod() throws MyException, MyException, MyException {
```

I can't think of a reason why I would want to do this. I have been searching for a while but I am not being able to find if there is a resource that explains why is this acceptable or how could it be good. Can anyone point me to some resource about this?

Comment: What do you think `throws` means?

Comment: Syntax sometimes allows many non-logical things, question is why would you write such a thing?

Comment: You can only throw one exception from a method because doing so transfers control away from the method. i.e. no more code from the method is executed when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I think it's all about syntax, it will work as if you wrote `throws MyException`. Restricting that, would be a superfluous check by the compiler.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why I would declare a variable `int useless = 0;` and never use it, but Java lets me. Maybe you'd want to write it that way to increase readability.

Comment: It's a type definition. Why would the compiler care if you declare it multiple times? How many other places in the java lingo is declaring a particular type multiple times a problem? I would expect a problem only where a variable name is concerned

Comment: That is only a redundant declaration of one  exception type that could be thrown by a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the JLS that prevents you from specifying the same exception type (or even subtypes) in the `throws` clause.  The only restriction, according to the [JLS, Section 8.4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6), is:

> **It is a compile-time error if an *ExceptionType* mentioned in a `throws` clause is not a subtype (§4.10) of `Throwable`.**

So, this compiles:

```
throws RedundantException, RedundantException, RedundantException
```

My IDE warns me of "duplicate throws", but it's not a compiler error.

I see no good reason ever to do this.  It has never occurred to me even to attempt this.

This compiles, even if `MySubclassException` subclasses `MyException`:

```
throws MyException, MySubclassException, MyException, MySubclassException
```

The only reason I can think of to list subclass exception types in the `throws` clause is to document in your own Javadocs that the subclass may be thrown, so it can be handled separately.

```
@throws MyException If something general went wrong.
@throws MySubclassException If something specific went wrong.
```

Even so, my IDE warns me of "a more general exception" in the list.

Incidentally, it doesn't seem to matter whether any of the exception types in the examples above are checked.

Comment: A practical example: some methods in java.nio throw IOException and also an "optional specific exception" like FileAlreadyExistsException (a subtype of IOException).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [rgettman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28309221/3614835), there's no semantic meaning to the duplicate `throws` declarations.  However, `javac` still records them in the compiled class file, making them available to reflection, as can be seen in the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IOException,
            IOException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Arrays.stream(Main.class.getMethod("main", String[].class).getExceptionTypes())
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

which prints

```
class java.io.IOException
class java.io.IOException
class java.io.IOException
class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

This isn't useful (and probably exposes buggy consumers of `Method.getExceptionTypes()`), but it is a behavioral difference caused by the duplicate `throws` declarations.